# How to a raise a domain event for the entity when the entity is created in clean architecture

Tags: clean-architecture, ardalis-cleanarchitecture

I have a project created using the [clean architecture template](https://github.com/ardalis/CleanArchitecture#using-the-dotnet-cli-template).

If I want a domain event be raised when a new project is created, where do I add that?

If I have to raise an event whenever a new item be added to a project, I can accomplish that in the [Project entity as shown here](https://github.com/ardalis/CleanArchitecture/blob/af7379fedcef0176f3f1dfc0dc41bf047c3843db/src/Clean.Architecture.Core/ProjectAggregate/Project.cs#L27).

Similarly for [MarkCompletion of a ToDoItem as done here](https://github.com/ardalis/CleanArchitecture/blob/af7379fedcef0176f3f1dfc0dc41bf047c3843db/src/Clean.Architecture.Core/ProjectAggregate/ToDoItem.cs#L18).

But its not clear where do I put the code to raise an event when a new Project is created?

One option is doing something like the [following in Create End Point here](https://github.com/ardalis/CleanArchitecture/blob/af7379fedcef0176f3f1dfc0dc41bf047c3843db/src/Clean.Architecture.Web/Endpoints/ProjectEndpoints/Create.cs#L37).

```cs
    newProject.Events.Add(new ProjectCreatedEvent(newProject));
```

But this is in UI, away from the domain model, and so does not feel right.

The other option is using [ef core interceptors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors#savechanges-interception). So when ever save changes is called, just [raise event as appropriate something like here](https://jaliyaudagedara.blogspot.com/2020/12/ef-core-50-savechanges-events-and.html).

And if I add event in Project ctor, then this is triggered even in case of an update.

```cs
      public Project(string name)
      {
        Name = Guard.Against.NullOrEmpty(name, nameof(name));
        
        var newProjectCreatedEvent = new NewProjectCreatedEvent(this);
        
        Events.Add(newProjectCreatedEvent);
      }
```

Are there any better options/patterns?

Any pointer is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you need to raise a domain event on project creation I would create a factory method that publishes the event.

You can use a static method or implement a factory object.

```cs
public class Project : BaseEntity, IAggregateRoot
{
    public static Project newProject(string name)
    {
        var project = new Project(name);
        
        var newProjectCreatedEvent = new NewProjectCreatedEvent(project);
    
        Events.Add(newProjectCreatedEvent);
        return project;
    }

    private Project(string name)
    {
      Name = Guard.Against.NullOrEmpty(name, nameof(name));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I also added a pvt parameter less ctor also like this. private Project() {  }. And Yes, I am aware that Ef Core will take care of materializing entities even with pvt ctors.